# undefined method `location' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f834658ea50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models: Event and Location.  Location has_many events and an event belongs_to a location.  A location has an attribute called "city".  In a controller, I have the following code:

```
@locations = Location.all.includes(:events)
@events = @locations.collect{|l| l.events}
@events.each do |event|
    puts "event is #{event.inspect}"
    puts "event location is #{event.location}"
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `location' for #<Event::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f834658ea50>
```

I know that all events have a location, so this should work.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fail if any of your locations has no events associated with it.
You can try to ensure you have no nil elements in your array:

```
@locations = Location.all.includes(:events)
@events = @locations.collect{|l| l.events}.
  flatten.
  reject{|e| e.nil?}
@events.each do |event|
    puts "event is #{event.inspect}"
    puts "event location is #{event.location}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `@locations.collect` call is returning an array of `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, which is why the error.  You could either pick the first element from the collection as follows if that is what you need:

```
@events = @locations.collect{|l| l.events}
@events.each do |event|
    puts "event is #{event.first.inspect}"
    puts "event location is #{event.first.location}"
end
```

Or you could [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the result of `collect` as:

```
@events = @locations.collect{|l| l.events}.flatten
@events.each do |event|
    puts "event is #{event.inspect}"
    puts "event location is #{event.location}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get 'undefined method `location' for nil:NilClass'.  I checked and all of my events are not nil and have defined locations, so I'm not sure why it's coming up as nil

Comment: Which one did you try?  Also can you inspect the object within `each` to ensure it is not `nil`.  Also, how are you checking events are not `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@events = Event.includes(:location).select('events.*, locations.city')
```

Now in view you can access locations' city as

```
<% @events.each do |e|%>
  <%= e.city %>
<% end %>
```